# How to play music files directly from folders?

Tags: nautilus, music

I would love to, while in a given folder, right-click on it and choose **play**, to play all music files in that folder (and subfolders if any).

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: VLC specific question ignoring non-music files: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551445/play-all-music-files-in-a-folder-from-the-command-line-ignoring-non-music-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this end up working for me:

http://mundogeek.net/nautilus-scripts/#nautilus-play-banshee

:) Yupi.

Comment: If the script provided by dv3500ea works on all (or almost all)  ubuntu systems and not in mine, I will switch the answer for his post instead of this. However, this was, in fact the solution found.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this with a Nautilus script.

First install a ruby package

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-1.9.1
```

Then copy this text into a text editor and save the file in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`. Call it something like 'Play'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
require 'find'

PLAYER = "banshee"
PLAYER_OPTIONS = ["--play-enqueued"]

def play *f
    IO.popen [PLAYER, *PLAYER_OPTIONS, *f] do |io|
        io.read
    end
end

def is_audio f
    begin
        io = IO.popen ['file', '--mime-type', f]
        op = io.read.split(' ')
        r = op[op.length-1] =~ /audio/
        io.close
        r
    rescue
    end
end

files = []

ARGV.each do |f|
    if File.directory? f
        Find.find f do |f|
            files << f if is_audio(f)
        end
    else
        files << f if is_audio(f)
    end
end

play(*files)
```

Open `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` in the file manager, right click on the file, click properties and make it executable.

You can now right click on some files and select **scripts -> Play** to play all of the music files you have selected.

Comment: I've followed everything but, nothing happens when I select scripts -> Play :( It doesn't even open banshee.

Comment: This definitely works. Make sure you copied the whole of the text. It is very easy to miss of the last line when you select the text. You may find it easier to copy from http://paste.ubuntu.com/601332/

Comment: Nope. I don't doubt the script work. But it not even starts the program, so even if I didn't add the last line (that I did), it should at least open it. I've remake the steps. No luck. Perhaps something to do with my own system configuration somehow.

Comment: I've called Play. No extension. Should I called it Play.sh or something ? Or Play.rb ?

Comment: The extension makes no difference. As long as you have ruby-1.9.1 installed and the file is made executable, this should work. I don't really know what's going wrong.

Comment: I do have ruby. I do see the ruby on my icon. :)Just for curiosity, I could test the script If I know how to debug it, (some sort of alert, so that I could understand where does it stops. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably silly answer but I just right clicked and selected "Open With Other Application... " then I selected my music player which is Audacious. Only drawback is that now every folder has an option to open with Audacious but I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very old thread.
However, somebody else may eventualy get here.
There is no need to write a script or install any Nautilus' plugin to play all media in a folder.
Just right-click the folder and click in "Open" (there should have an ">" at the right of "Open"). Then click on "Open With..." and select the media player you of your choice. VLC works for both musics and videos. It will play all media alphabetically, one after the other.