# Play all audio files in a directory from the command line ignoring non-audio files

Tags: vlc

If I do:

```
vlc dir
```

it also plays files like images for 10 seconds. Is there a way to prevent that and play only the music?

I also have music files on arbitrary subfolders: `dir/jazz`, `dir/classic`, `dir/jazz/miles-davies`, etc.

I can do it with `find` and some bash-fu, but I'd prefer a simple `vlc` solution, or some other very simple solution that does not involve coding a complex script, in particular deciding what is a music file or not.

I have seen: [How to play music files directly from folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38167/how-to-play-music-files-directly-from-folders) , but it is not VLC specific.

Also opened on the bug tracker: https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/12819

Comment: Where is your dir directory located? full path?

Comment: @KasiyA why does that matter? It's on the current directory.

Comment: You want to play all music files in your dir directory and also all musics in its sub-directory?right?

Comment: please go to your dir directory. then run `for file in . ;do vlc "$file" ;done &`

Comment: I have done that. That `for` look has no effect, it is the same as `vlc .`, which is the same that I've done.

Comment: But why `vlc .` not work for you. it works for me without any problem and it plays only all my music files.

Comment: But it also plays image files which is why I asked this question.

Comment: for me it's not play. what is your vlc version?

Comment: 2.1.4 is the version

Comment: Then I don't know what is the problem. mine also is 2.1.4

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command to play only MP3s

`vlc folder/*.mp3` (GUI)

`cvlc folder/*.mp3` (CLI)

You can specify additional formats using `*.ogg` etc.

If there are subfolders -

`vlc folder/*/./*.mp3` (GUI)

`cvlc folder/*/./*.mp3` (CLI)

Comment: But does it work if there are multiple levels? And I'd like to avoid typing several possible extensions.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an old question, but if you're still wondering then I'd do:

```
find . -name *.mp3 -exec cvlc '{}' +
```

Which would find all mp3 files and then plays them in cvlc.  The plus on the end, as apposed to semicolon means that you will use a single instance of vlc, rather than having it restart after every single song which might lead to longer breaks between songs.

Comment: Multiple extensions: `find . -type f \( -name ".mp3" -or -name ".ogg" \) -exec cvlc '{}' +`